# Is there a way to make the textfield appear in different color without affecting the semi-transparent background?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I was wondering if it's possible to change the color of the textfield inside the blue border itself, without changing the surrounding area that is semi-transparent. Here is a screenshot of what I have:
[image: textfield]

Here is a screenshot of what I wish to have:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textFieldContent = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VisualEffectView()
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1))
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 1.16)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 2 / 3)
                }
                HStack {
                    TextField("Send a message", text: $textFieldContent)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                        .focusable(false)
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Send")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }
                .padding(1)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .padding()
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        .padding(.trailing, 0)
                        .padding(.top, 0)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topTrailing)
                .padding(.trailing, 0)
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct VisualEffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        let view = NSVisualEffectView()
        view.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        view.state = .active
        view.material = .underWindowBackground
        return view
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Also, as a bonus, is it even possible to have the textfield surrounding the area/box more transparent or clear with some blur? As shown in the second screenshot.

I tried changing the textfield using `.background(Color.blue)` for example, but the whole thing looks different then. See below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it:

use `.textFieldStyle(.plain)` to erase styling and build the textbox yourself.

```
HStack {
    TextField("Send a message", text: $textFieldContent)
        .textFieldStyle(.plain) // 
        .padding(6)
        .padding(.horizontal, 6)
        .background(Color.black.cornerRadius(6))
    
        .padding()
        .background(Color.clear)
        .focusable(false)
    Button(action: {
        
    }) {
        Text("Send")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
}
.padding(.horizontal, 20)
.padding(1)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
```

[image]

With this solution, you have **no focus ring**, but in your target example it's also not visible.

---

It was not your question, but I think it makes the code more readable to use `.padding(.horizontal, 20)` rather than the two padding for `.leading` and `.trailing` in different places.